# Class cannot find another class in the same namespace

Tags: c#, types, namespaces, type-resolution

I have a C# WebApp that we are doing for a client. I have two classes in the project, defined (in separate files) as such...

**A general utility library:**

```
namespace Client.WebApp {
    public static class General {
        public static MyDbClass GetDB() {
            //<creates and returns MyDbClass here>
        }
    }
}
```

**A PageBase class:**

```
namespace Client.WebApp {
    public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected MyDbClass dbo { get; set; }

        public PageBase() {
            dbo = General.GetDB();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error from the `dbo = General.GetDB();` line:
**`The name 'General' does not exist in the current context Client.WebApp.`**

- I have double-checked that the namespace is spelled right in both files.
- I have tried adding the top-level namespace `Client.WebApp` as a using directive in the pagebase file.
- I have tried fully qualifying the name as in `dbo = Client.WebApp.General.GetDB();`

Nothing has helped and it insists that my `General` class does not exist. 
Funny thing is that while the build hits this error and stops, the code-editor does not see this error, and the statement does not get red-under-squiggled.

The project is targeting Framework v.4.5.2, and I am working in VS 2015.

Comment: Are both classes in the same assembly?

Comment: Avoid using `My`. It will conflict with the built-in `My` namespace for anyone using VB that may want to use your assembly.

Comment: Yes, they are both in the core WebApp project, not in external DLL projects. The namespace is just an example. I changed the name of it because the namespace setup by whoever first created the project includes the client name. I changed the example code to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: Is the `General` class syntactically correct?

Comment: Beats me... Try a Clean and then a Rebuild.

Comment: The `General` class has no red squiggles and is not reporting any errors at build time. As far as I can see it is correct.

Comment: Are you running VS2015? I had this problem with 2015 and it drove me nuts. It worked when I closed VS and reopened. I have no clue as it stilll does this from time to time.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea - nope, no luck with the C&R.

Comment: Try manually deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders from your project directories within the solution. (All project directories.) Then try another clean and build.

Comment: @Anonymous - yeah, VS 2015. Just tried that... no joy.

Comment: Can you copy output of a verbose build?

Comment: Is that the _only_ compiler error you get?

Comment: @DStanley - yup; that is the lone and only error.

Comment: Try copying the class into the same file as `PageBase`, it may be that you accidentally set the settings for the `General` cs file to be something other than "Compile", can you check the file properties, specifically the Build Action?

Comment: @Ron might be on to something, give it a shot. Make sure the Build Action is set to Compile for the General class's cs file.

Comment: @RonBeyer - BAM! That was it! What's weird is I literally just added this file as a new Class file from the "Add New Item" dialog, but somehow, the build action was set to `Content`. If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it. I just assumed VS would add a new code file as `Compile`. LOL Silly me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a strange error, in my VS2015 if I set a file Build Action to anything other than "Compile", I get an error underline on any type for that file.

Anyway the solution here is to verify that the Build Action is set to "Compile", I'm not sure why adding a new file would have set the build action to anything other than "Compile". I've also tested trying to add new files in multiple ways (select a text file template and just name it something.cs), it still sets it as "Compile". You should verify that your VS2015 instance is updated with the latest updates.

Comment: Man, you just helped me figure out something that was driving me crazy!  For some reason one file had gotten set to Build Action = Content, not Compile.  Super non-obvious.  Finding your answer made me check.

Comment: If the file is set to "Compile" you might just have to restart visual studio entirly. This bug seems to have stuck around with VS2017

Comment: Confirmed, closing VS17 down, reopening, Clean, Rebuild seems to solve it.

Comment: As ecnepsnai said... Restart fixed it. Thx

Comment: still a prob in VS2017.  I changed the problematic file from Compile==>to Content==>then back to Compile and it suddenly "found" it again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: "type or namespace could not be found". It turned out that class was in a file with the "Build Action" property set to "None", meaning the file was not being compiled. I set it to "C# Compiler", that solved it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me sometimes. Closing visual studio and opening it again always fixes it for me.

Comment: Unbelievable, we are in 2024 and still same issue and solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figure it out that if we create a file in a folder which suppose to have content files it set that file's build type content automatically. In my Case I create a file under app_code folder and it is a class file but the build type is set to Content which make it unavailable for any other classes i have.

May be it has any other reasons too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new Class in the Project folder and then move it to the folder, you want it to be.